# Failing to connect and output my json requests

Tags: php, json

So I have access to a public web API and I'm trying to pull information from it and use it in a PHP if statement. I have tried a few different ways but each time I fail? I will post all of my failed attempts to see if anyone knows what I'm doing wrong...

This is the JSON file;

```
{
  "players": [
    {
      "SteamId": "76561198074117457",
      "CommunityBanned": false,
      "VACBanned": true,
      "NumberOfVACBans": 1,
      "DaysSinceLastBan": 738,
      "NumberOfGameBans": 0,
      "EconomyBan": "none"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Attempt 1 using a PHP function**
    (php file)

```
<?php      
  function VACBanned($vacban) {    
    if ($vacban == "false") {
      return "";
    }
    elseif ($vacban == "true") {
      return "<p>This user has a vac ban...</p>";
    } 
  }
?>
```

(index file)

```
<html>    
  <body>    
    <?=VACBanned($json['players'][0]['VACBanned']);?>    
  </body>    
</html>
```

This would output the following error;

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: players in index.php on line 13
```

I initially thought that the API must not have been correctly connecting, so I went into the PHP file and echoed my user ID like so `$json["players"][0]["SteamId"];` and it worked... But when I went and attempted to perform the same thing in the Index `<?php echo $json["players"][0]["SteamId"];?>` I got the error again? When I did this in the php file `$test =  $json["players"][0]["SteamId"];` and this in the index `<?php echo $test;?>`it echoed my steam id?????? I tried to just call the if statement in the index like so

```
<?php
  if ($vac_ban == "false") {
    return "123";
  }
  else {
    return "<div class='ban_vac'><p>1 VAC BAN<br>76 Days Ago</p></div>";
  }
?>
```

and $vac_ban would be stated in the php file as `= $json["players"][0]["VACBanned"];` but that just made it outpute everything above the `<?` tag and nothing below it. **Note** the whole time during this I had the two files connected using `include('filename');` and `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1);` and the json is decoded `json_decode(file_get_contents($api_url), true);`

Comment: how json decoded into array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I worked it out for anyone who might be having this issue, I just put my PHP code into the one document, it looks messy but works :)

Answer (score 0):

You must decode json before use with PHP:

```
$array = json_decode($data, true);
```

Now you can do what you want:

```
VACBanned($array['players'][0]['VACBanned']);
```

Take a look: [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: Yea sorry I forgot to add that, I have edited my post :) but yes I have json_decode(file_get_contents($api_url), true); in my php file

Comment: Are you sure than you are passing the correct url to `file_get_contents()`? What is the output of this: `var_dump(file_get_contents($api_url));`

Comment: yes like I said I thought that as well but when I echoed `$json["players"][0]["SteamId"];` I got the correct response from the JSON????

Comment: Without seeing the whole code is a bit difficult to determine. Are you using any framework? How are you passing the data to `index.php`?

Comment: I would be happy to privately message you regarding the code but I'm currently just using the latest PHP framework and I'm using `include (file_name)` in my index to connect the two files.